# Incorrect syntax near '00' on manual migration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am just starting out with Asp .Net and am trying to manually add data to my database.
I have the below migration, adding `dateTime` to the relevant field in the db, but I am getting an error, `Incorrect syntax near '00'`.

Not sure what this means, as far as I know I am passing the correct data type to the database.

Any ideas?

```
namespace VidlyNew.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class AddBirthDateValues : DbMigration
    {

        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql($"UPDATE Customers SET CustomerBirthDate = {DateTime.Parse("19-12-1990")} WHERE Id = 1");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace VidlyNew.Models
{
    public class Customers
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CustomerBirthdate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Updated following input:

```
SqlParameter DateParam1 = new SqlParameter("@CustomerBirthDate_1", new DateTime(1990,12,01));
Sql("UPDATE Customers SET CustomerBirthDate = @CustomerBirthDate_1 WHERE Id = 1", DateParam1);
```

However now I have the following error:

```
Cannot convert from 'System.Data.Sqlclient.Sqlparameter' to 'bool'
```

`SqlParameter()` signatures.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your SQL statement ends up as something like `...SET CustomerBirthDate = 1990/12/19 00:00:00 ...` depending on your culture, which in not valid SQL syntax (date values supplied as strings must be surrounded by quotes).

You should be using parameters instead of inline SQL to provide values.  Since you wrap that with a `Sql` call, it *may* mean refactoring that to allow the passing or one or more parameters:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@CustomerBirthDate",new DateTime(1990,12,19));
Sql("UPDATE Customers SET CustomerBirthDate = @CustomerBirthDate  WHERE Id = 1", p);
```

While you *could* just surround the value in single quotes (`SET CustomerBirthDate = '1990-12-19'`), I would get into the habit of using parameters to pass values.  It will mean less formatting problems (especially with date/time) and less vulnerability to SQL injection.

Comment: Seems to have changed the error to, `cannot convert from 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter' to 'bool'`. See edit above

Comment: Post the declaration of the `Sql` function.  It may already have an overload that takes a `bool` - you may need to add another that takes a `SqlParameter`

Comment: Posted the parameters above, only one takes  `bool`, `isNullable`, the date field in my model is nullable.

Comment: I'm talking about the `Sql` function that you're calling, not the `SqlParameter` constructor.

Comment: Might sound stupid now, not sure what you mean exactly, is the function not the `Sql` I have in my post?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't directly assign c# datetime to SQL Server datetime in your query.**

Problem is in the part of the query where you are trying to assign c# datetime to sql server column. You could do this instead..

```
Sql("UPDATE Customers SET CustomerBirthDate = '12-19-1990' WHERE Id = 1");
```

SQL Server attempts to convert string to DateTime (or Date) based on your target type. If your date is in SQL Server acceptable format, the casting will be implicitly done.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is being generated as something like:

```
UPDATE Customers SET CustomerBirthDate = 19/12/1990 12:00:00 AM WHERE Id = 1
```

Depending on your culture. This is an *invalid* date for SQL Server.

You can simply write something like:

```
UPDATE Customers SET CustomerBirthDate = '1990/12/19' WHERE Id = 1
```

Since your date is hard coded. If it's not hard-coded, use prepared statements.

Comment: I did try that previously, but SQL Server interpreted the date as a string still, so there was a conflict with the db, which is expecting a `DateTime`

Comment: @RichC It depends on your locale that your SQL server is using. You could also try `'1990-12-20'`